# Spotfire HTML tables - conditional formatting with variable values

Tags: javascript, html, spotfire

I've got a html table I've created in spotfire - each cell a calculated value - with a slider for the user to adjust dates they're interested in.

One column is a 'vs last year' - for negative values (formatted as negatives in brackets with '#,0.0%; (#,0.0%); -' as the custom formatting).

I colour the negative values red with the following javascript:

```
function BlackRedText() {
var cellval = $(this).text();
if (cellval.indexOf('(') > -1) {
    $(this).addClass('Red')
} else{ //if (cellval.indexOf('(') === -1) {
    $(this).addClass('Black')
    } 
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
$('td.KPI span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization span').each(BlackRedText);
});
```

These have corresponding styles:

```
.Black{color: black !important;color: black;}
.Red{color: red !important; color: red;}
```

Then rows:

```
<td  class =" KPI "  align = right> (100) </td>
```

Will show up in red. The problem is that when the slider moves times such that these values are positive again they are still keeping the red colour.

**Positive values start off black and will turn red with the slider but they won't return to black afterwards.**

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

--Edit: I had wondered if the classes were changing (it looks for a KPI class) but I added in rows to check for Red and Black classes too but that hasn't helped.

--Edit 2: There seems to be no problem with the scripts written, only with spotfire refreshing these - switching tabs and back again corrected the colour problems so I've changed it so the slider limits are only applied once I've pressed a button which also refreshes the table - bit of a hack so anyone who spots a better way let me know.

Comment: looks like you found a solution but be wary of adding tons of Calculated Values. each one of those is a VisualContent object; in other words, a visualization. they can easily bog down your local machine, but can cripple a Web Player.